# How do I compare dates with a spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that I want to conditionally format according to dates. If a date is 7 days away, I want the cell to turn red, if a date is 14 days away, I want it to turn green, etc.

The first step to doing this, I figured, would be to create a simple conditional format script, where if a date is today, it would be highlighted. But my code doesn't work :(

```
function formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // get the sheet
  var columnF = sheet.getRange(2, 6, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1); // get all the rows
  var fValues = columnF.getValues(); // get the values
  var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy"); // get today's date
  for (var i = 0; i < fValues.length; i++) { // repeat loop
    if (fValues[i][0] == today) { // if the date in the cell is today's date...
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 6, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('green'); // ...turn that cell green
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not convert your date to a string, you can parse the date in days, month and years like in Srik's answer, or you can also compare dates using their native values like below, it becomes easier to calculate other dates... I created a few variables to simplify the math :

`day` = the number of milliseconds in a day

`today` = today's date at 00:00 (in days)

```
function formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // get the sheet
  var columnF = sheet.getRange(2, 6, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).setBackgroundColor('white'); // get all the rows and clear colors
  var fValues = columnF.getValues(); // get the values
  var day = 24*3600*1000
  var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day); // get date today
  for (var i = 0; i < fValues.length; i++) { // repeat loop
    var dataday = parseInt(fValues[i][0].getTime()/day)
    Logger.log(dataday+' = '+today)
    if (dataday == today-7) {sheet.getRange(i + 2, 6, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('red')}
    else if (dataday == today-14){sheet.getRange(i + 2, 6, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('green')}
    else if (dataday == today-21){sheet.getRange(i + 2, 6, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('blue')}
  }
}
```

Test sheet available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dGN5ckx0YnlBdnF1UlhEd1c4a193dnc)

Comment: I am trying to use the same code to get date values that are entered in my sheet. The dates are in this format - mm/dd/yyyy. I am using the same code above to check if the date in the sheet is more than 30 days old by comparing it with today's date. I am getting the following error - "getTime() can not be used on object". I understand this happens if I am not working with date objects but I have no idea how to correct this. Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: is the cell in which you read the value a "date formatted cell" or a string ? you can check that by clicking on it, it should open a calendar if it's a date cell... and do nothing if it's not.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compare Date object directly. You need to compare by date, month and year. Try something like

```
function formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // get the sheet
  var columnF = sheet.getRange(2, 6, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1); // get all the rows
  var fValues = columnF.getValues(); // get the values
  var today = new Date(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < fValues.length; i++) { // repeat loop
    var fDate = new Date(fValues[i][0]);
    if (fDate.getDate() == today.getDate() && 
        fDate.getMonth() == today.getMonth() && 
        fDate.getFullYear() == today.getFullYear()) { // if the date in the cell is today's date...
      sheet.getRange(i + 2, 6, 1, 1).setBackgroundColor('green'); // ...turn that cell green
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So what if I wanted to turn cells that had a date 2 weeks from now or less green? Is that not possible because I have to reference the exact  day, month, and year?

Answer (score 0):

I would add to Serge's post that in line 8 you might be better off not using the getDate() call. This is because the entries in the fValues array are not necessarily dates if you have copy/pasted the values in the sheet itself.