# Comparing dates from range to today's date in Google Apps Script

Tags: date, google-apps-script

I'm looking to compare dates pulled from a spreadsheet to today's date, using this post as a reference: [How do I compare dates with a spreadsheet using Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350671/how-do-i-compare-dates-with-a-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script)

When I run the script, I get a 'Cannot find function getTime() in object' message for the line that declares var dataDay (first line after for loop).

When I run the debugger, the values in the position values[i][18] though say it is a date object. Any thoughts here?

```
function gantChart() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Copy of 2016 Gift Tracking");
  var values = ss.getRange(3,1,ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var day = 24*3600*1000
  var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);
  var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Get chart automation");
  for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var dataDay = parseInt(values[i][18].getTime()/day);
    if(dataDay > today) {
     }
  } 
  debugger;
}
```

Comment: try replacing `values[i][18]` with `new Date(values[i][18])`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks, Serge. Also, I'm excited to dive into your book!

Answer (score 0):

From a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349925/comparing-dates-from-range-to-todays-date-in-google-apps-script#comment58407691_35349925) by Serge insas

> `try replacing values[i][18] with new Date(values[i][18])`