# How to create conditional status based on date in Google apps script. i have 2 column. column 1 is Final date and column 2 is status

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have question.
so when Final date >= Today , Status "Active".
and
when Final date <= Today , Status "Offline"

I haven't found a way to change status with the date by app script. Please help Me

I want to change the status based on today with appscript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I compare a date in a Google Sheets cell to today? - Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75442131/how-can-i-compare-a-date-in-a-google-sheets-cell-to-today-apps-script)